# (INSERT + On DuplicateKey UPDATE) + UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

- the column of value ( $_SESSION['val1'] ) in both tables are connected with index (foreign key)
- the 'process' method is for prepared statement
- i want to combine $get and $get2 in mysql

code...

```
$get = $call->process("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE col4 = ?, col5 = UTC_TIMESTAMP()", 
array($_SESSION['val1+val2'], $_SESSION['val1'], $_SESSION['val2'], 'OK', 'NOOK'));

  if($get)
  {
  $get2 = $call->process("UPDATE table2 SET col8 = col8 + 1 WHERE colval1 = ?", 
                array($_SESSION['val1'])); 
  }
```

should i create stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/replace.html) might come in handy

Answer (score 0):

see manual - google "insert or update mysql"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

without schema, it's hard to help You more